# How to exclude search results that have a particular tag?

Tags: support

Is there a way to *exclude* from search results all posts that have a particular tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, although it must be a part of some other search. That is, you can't search just for "All posts that don't have this tag".

As part of your search, include `-[tag]` in the search string. For example, if I wanted to search something on Meta Mathematics, but not posts with [support](/questions/tagged/support), then I'd include `-[support]` in my search string. This will then give me my search results without any results that are tagged as such (or in the case of answers, whose associated question is tagged as such).

Comment: Hi ... are there any search guidelines?

Comment: @hasExams Head to [our base search page](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=), on the right there's a little thing that says 'Advanced Search Tips'. It will contain all of our special search systems that you can use. If you hover your mouse over any individual one in that list, it'll give a more in-depth explanation of what that search effect does. And if you have any further questions, well, please don't hesitate to ask. ♪

Comment: I was wondering if I could use latex to search ... I am looking for expressions.

Comment: @hasExams The issue of searching formulas on meta.SE was discussed before; the built-in search is not really designed with latex markup in mind. You may be interested in [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6180/75064) and [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1394/75064). ¶ Also, on the subject of your post I found that `-[tag] views:0` is a shorter search command with same effect. Operator `views:0` is understood as $\ge 0$, and it's impossible for any post to have a negative number of views.